# Eclipse Error: "Failed to connect to remote VM"

Tags: java, eclipse

I’m getting the following error when I start Debug from the Eclipse IDE.

> Message: `“Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection Refused”`

What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you trying to debug a local application or a remote one?

Comment: Note that if you're trying to debug a local application and you're getting this error, it could be because your /etc/hosts (or  C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) file has a bogus mapping for "localhost". I've seen that before.

Comment: Check if you wrongly specified Port 8080 instead of 8000. It was happened with me.

Comment: If you're debugging a remote java application, open the debug perspective, check whether there is any vm already attached. Eclipse could not show the debug perspective util it encouter a breakpoint.

Comment: I right-clicked the Debug perspective button and selected reset. It worked accordingly.

Comment: make sure your application server is up and listening to the correct port.

Comment: Note, the port can only accept **one** connection and any subsequent connections will be rejected.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you setup the remote VM to accept connections?

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=10000,suspend=n yourServer
```

Is there a firewall in the way?

Are you specifying the correct host / port?

Are you connected to a VPN?

Comment: The gotcha for me was accidentally adding the debug flags to the end of the command line, so they were just passed to the program itself.

Comment: What is the param "yourServer" match with ?
 It seems to be a java class ... How to setup it correctly ?

Comment: my Debug Configurations in eclipse had changed my port number. :(

Comment: I had reinstalled (via RPM) and forgotten to modify my /etc/init.d script to include the jpda flag

Comment: Closing the VPN connection helped me :)

Comment: are you running this command in remote machine or in your machine where eclipse is present?

Comment: For me, it was a port issue as suggested in the second question, I had to switch to port 5005 (default)

Comment: If the port number and hostname(mine's localhost), what else could be the issue?

Comment: Eclipse can be weird sometimes and it doesn't automatically switch to the "Debug" perspective when you run the "Debug Configuration". After a successful debug session has been established, if you run it again thinking that it didn't run and/or silently failed, then you get the error message: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. So, always switch to the "Debug" perspective to see what's going on.

Answer (score 39):

Use `0.0.0.0` for addresses to be able to connect form any remote machine i.e.:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

Comment: This appears to be a recent change (JDK 9+)...if you only specified the port, it would accept connections from any IP to that port. Now, you need to manually specify the IP or use 0.0.0.0 if you want anything to connect.

Comment: fix it for me under:
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I wish this answer had been easier to find...I almost gave up trying to configure remote debug with Maven on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Or use * instead of 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 33):

## Remove your proxy from eclipse!

Go to network Connections within General Preferences ( Windows -> Preferences ) and set "Active Provider" to "Direct"

[image: remove proxy]

Reboot your Eclipse after that

Comment: Are you still with this problem?

Comment: This is in Windows->Preferences

Comment: Doesn‘t work for me.

Comment: Worked for me in year 2023!

Answer (score 4):

David Citron is right -- if localhost is not resolving properly, it can cause this problem.  Here's how to test:

If it works when your PC is **not connected** to the net (no WiFi, no network cables).  If it **does work** under those conditions, then it may be that you need to make sure that addresses are resolving to `localhost` properly. The messages that DDMS and adb.exe use for debugging and communicating to the VM must properly resolve to `localhost` on your PC.  (Yes, it's odd that other commands using DDMS & adb work just fine but debugging doesn't.  Seems that something in DDMS or adb needs to be standardized so they all work under the same conditions.)

If you need to make sure that things are resolving to `localhost` properly:

1) Make sure that this line is in your `/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`  file:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

(you can have any amount of whitespace between "127.0.0.1" and "localhost")

And -- as David Citron suggested -- make sure that the hosts file is valid and doesn't have cruft or errors in it.

2)  If that doesn't work, then you may need to also add your PC's IPv4 address to the hosts file, and resolve it to `localhost`. (You can find out the IPv4 address for your machine with the `ipconfig` command.)  If, for example, your machine's IPv4 address is `192.168.1.100` then you'd add the line

```
192.168.1.100  localhost
```

to your hosts file.  (You can add it below the "127.0.0.1  localhost" line in the file.)

You can verify that adb (and your emulator if you're running one) is listening on ports by using the `netstat -b` command. (Note that you need admin privileges for the `-b` option. I open a command window using "Run as Administrator.")

Comment: and for mac and linux?

Comment: @Xanlantos you'll need to check other answers

Answer (score 3):

Possible Cause for this error:

1. Your Remote Java Application is not running.
2. Check your Host and Port, many times these entries are not correct.
3. Firewall not allowing access to your remote port.

You can also check this [how to guide on eclipse remote debugging](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) for more details.

Comment: To check third option , telent can be used. Eg: telnet <host> <port>

Comment: Any other possible causes for this error? For me, the host and the port number are correct and I'am trying to debug a service running locally

Answer (score 2):

add to your run script:

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8787
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
export JPDA_HOST=localhost

JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=n $JAVA_OPTS
```

Comment: Where you wants to run these scripts ? Locally or remote VM machine where we're actually trying to connect?

Answer (score 2):

Our development image only has the Tomcat service installation on it, so setting the environment variables, etc., didn't have any effect.  If you need to do this through the Tomcat Windows service, there are a few things you'll need to be aware of:

- David Citron's comment was the last bit that I needed to get my connection working.  The hosts file on our machines has localhost commented out (it's supposedly resolved through the DNS, but that doesn't work for the debug connection).  I uncommented it and was able to connect.
- If user access control is turned on, you'll need to use your admin credentials to access the services control panel or the Tomcat monitor app or whatever you're using to toggle the server state.  The monitor app (documented [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Tomcat6w%20monitor%20application)) is probably the best, because you can both edit the server settings for the debug options and start and stop the server.
- I thought that perhaps you would need to run Eclipse as an administrator to be able to terminate the Tomcat process, but you don't.  Once you have that remote attachment, you're able to work with the service up to termination.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it setting in Eclipse:

```
Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Debug --> Debugger timeout: 10000
```

Before I had set "`Debugger timeout: 3000`" and I had problems with timeout.

Comment: still getting "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused."

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me: edit the last line of tomcat `startup.sh` from

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"`
```

to

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000 export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket  
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is weird

1. Simply remove the all the break points
2. Restart tomcat in debug mode (using catalina.sh jpda start)
3. Now try to connect and it worked!!!!

Comment: its worked for me. first need to start the catalina(so only it can connect to the port) then start the debug in eclipse it will connect to the jpda. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the debug agent is binding to the wrong network interface.

I've just seen this when trying to debug a Windows 10 JVM inside a VirtualBox VM, and I'm trying to connect from Eclipse running on the VirtualBox host. In my case, the agent only bound to the `127.0.0.1` interface.

To fix, you can qualify the `address` including the IP of the interface you want to bind to. For example:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=192.168.0.5:8000,suspend=n <other arguments>
```

Comment: Was about to add same thing Dan.  The server I was trying to debug had two NICs, and the jdwp server was binding to the wrong one.  By explicitly setting `address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000` I was able to connect just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had and solved this problem by disconnecting from all remote Java applications in the debug window/perspective and restarting Eclipse. I could connect again after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and install again ADT android plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows os then replace line in tomcat configuration `Tomcat6\bin\startup.bat`.

Replace

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

with

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug an application working on Tomcat, make sure that your *Tomcat-folder/bin/startup.bat* (if using windows) contains the following lines:

```
set JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000

call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with Tomcat running on Ubuntu. The issue was selinux was enabled and for some reason it would not let Eclipse connect to the debugging port. Disabling selinux or putting it in permissive mode solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error for Weblogic after i installed Quicktime and removing QTJava.zip from classpath solves the problem.

https://blogs.oracle.com/adfjdev/entry/java_jre7_lib_ext_qtjava

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory value of the properties

- `MEM_PERM_SIZE_64BIT`
- `MEM_MAX_PERM_SIZE_64BIT`

in `setDomainEnv.cmd` file from `%weblogic_home%\user_projects\domains\your_domain\bin`

Answer (score 0):

I'll add one more possible solution, if you're running this on a virtual machine (vmware, etc.) , some other process on the host or other VM could already have the port you're trying to connect with.  Either stop that other process or choose another port.

Answer (score 0):

Create setenv.bat file in nib folder of Tomcat.
Add SET JPDA_ADDRESS = 8787 ; Override the jpda port
Open cmd, go to bin folder of Tomcat and Start tomcat using catalina jpda start
Set up a debug point on eclipse
Next compile your project.
Check localhost:8080/ 
Deploy the war or jar under webapps folder and this must deploy war on Tomcat.
Then send the request. the debug point will get hit
NOTE : Don't edit catalina.bat file. make changes in setenv.bat file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jboss:

change in the file jboss7.1.1\bin\standalone.conf.bat the line:

```
rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

to:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things mentioned here, but the below method worked for me:

Go to Debug Console of Eclipse, where you will find the name of the process which is already existing there.
Right click on that process and select "Terminate and Remove", this will terminate the process.
Now try initiating the process again and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i turn Windows Firewall **off**

1- Open Windows Firewall by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type firewall, and then click Windows Firewall.

2- Click Turn Windows Firewall on or off.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

3- Click Turn off Windows Firewall (not recommended) under each network location that you want to stop trying to protect, and then click OK.
Was this page helpful?

**Some times you need also**

1. To stop all Vpn client services (fortiClient ,vpn Client ...)
2. To stop Antivirus Firewall ( exemple Kaspersky => Configuration =>
   Anti-Hacker)

Answer (score 0):

I am using jboss so solution to your problem was restart.

```
service jboss-portal restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered like this in Hybris.

1. Check your port in Resource Monitor > Network. Check if other service is using your port.

1.2 If yes, then you need to change your properties in project.properties

1.3 Change your address, any available address. In my case, I changed from 8000 to 8080. then save.

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8080,suspend=n yourServer
```

2. In your console, rebuild your ant using command 'ant all'
3. Then debug again, using the command 'hybrisserver.bat debug'

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: For glassfish Server login via admin console -> Configurations -> server-config -> JVM-settings. * Remember to check Enable checkbox for Debug. Now
Note the address, this address will be used in port of eclipse Remote Java Application Debug.[Check the snap shot in glassfish server here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aioBF.png)