# When I debug my application I get frequently Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM

Tags: eclipse, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Error: “Failed to connect to remote VM”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975384/eclipse-error-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm)

When I debug my application I get frequently Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM
even If I try again it doesn't help, I need to restart Eclipse.

**Edit**
Not sure yet fully if the symptoms have to do with the fact that I get this error only when I launch Debug without a code modification. Whenever I do a modification to the source code and hit Debug it goes through, but if I don't it doesn't.

Comment: Is this a real device connected via USB or an AVD? If a real device, are you also using the USB to transfer files?

Comment: As in my tags, this is a real device. The USB is used for my Eclipse connection, I don't know what you mean if I use to transfer files. I can't see sdcard while connected to Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect answer (on the emulator side): deleted

Comment: Fails frequently for me on the emulator.  The emulator side has "Waiting for Debugger"... waiting for debugger to attach.  Oddly, there are dozens of Internet chat board posts about this.

Comment: And have you found a solution?

Comment: Not I.  It appears to be related to the error when the IDE complains that it cannot hotswap code.  That is, I notice it has not happened in any session where I have not received the complaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the eclipse plugin, just make a modification to the code and it will work.

Comment: I think resetting the adb is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by resetting ADB in eclipse.  Try the following:

1. Disconnect the device from USB.
2. Select the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse.
3. On the Devices tab of the perspective, select the menu then reset ADB.
4. Reconnect the device.