# How to toggle "Show Monitors" in STS (Spring Tool Suite) Debug View?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, remote-debugging, spring-tool-suite

In order to improve Remote Debugging performances, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433411/eclipse-java-remote-debugger-extremely-slow-over-vpn) SO thread I'm trying to disable in STS (not plain eclipse) the "Show Monitors" from Debug View, but cannot find either  the Menu Item or the icon.

As reference I also found the Eclipse Documentation mentioning the "Show Monitors" icon
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-showmonitors.htm

but not able to find it anywhere in STS.

Anyone know how to toggle it in STS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Debug view's context menu (click on the little triangle in the upper-right corner). Then goto "Java >> Show Monitors".

[image]

Comment: It works! Initial connection for remote-debugging is still slow but at least step-over step-into are much faster  now!! 
Do you know any further setting to improve perfomance of Remote Debugging initial connection to the JVM ?