# Remote debugging from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote a debug an application which is deployed through Websphere. I have all the port configured correctly on server side and on eclipse side. I can use

```
telnet host port
```

to connect to remote host and port correctly. But When I try to connect through remote debug through eclipse, I run into the error

```
Failed to connect to remote VM
  com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException
```

What can be the possible causes for this? I have checked and searched Stackoverflow for this error already. I have tried the most things from answer on this question [Eclipse Error: "Failed to connect to remote VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975384/eclipse-error-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What command line arguments are you providing to the JVM when you start WebSphere?

Comment: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777

Comment: And you're attempting to connect to port `7777`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to connect to 7777 through eclipse remote debugging option, but I get the error mentioned.

Comment: It would help if you show the configuration you added to Websphere and Eclipse to both expose and access the debug port. I mean, if you can't figure it out and you have all the settings in front of you, how would someone else figure it out with nothing to work from?

Comment: I added the snapshot of settings if that helps. This issue is trivial to me, I am running out of ideas why it might not be connecting. I have checked through telnet to see if this was a firewall issue, I have checked the port is open on the server and listening. Also I tried with a different computer and faced the same issue. Issue is particularly with server, so not sure if anything else i need to configure there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the port and it worked. It was a networking issue with that port of 7777.