# Eclipse Start Weblogic in debug Mode error : “Failed to connect to remote VM”

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, weblogic12c

I know this question may be asked several times, but my question is a little bit different.

I can start Weblogic server in Eclipse without error.

I tried to start in Eclipse Weblogic Server in debug mode to debug a LOCAL application (not remote debug), but I got the “Failed to connect to remote VM” error. To make sure the problem is from Eclipse, I started manually Weblogic with startWeblogic.cmd with `debugFlag=true` in the bin\setDomainEnv.cmd, and then in Eclipse tried debugging Remote Java Application with the same debug port, the debug worked without error.

I also tried to compare the output of both launch method, they both contain the option for "Starting WLS with line": `-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8022,server=y,suspend=n`. The only difference is that in Eclipse there's the java version, but no in Weblogic version.

I tried the solution in [Eclipse Error: “Failed to connect to remote VM”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975384/eclipse-error-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm), checking whether the debug port is occupied, and it is occupied by the same process java.

Another strange thing is that when I launch debug mode in Eclipse when the server is stopped, the error appears once. When I launch debug when in Eclipse when the server is started, the same error appears twice.

I'm using proxy in Eclipse, and I have to. But I was using the same configuration before when there was no such error.

Could you please help me with something I can check for the Weblogic Eclipse plugin? Thanks very much!

Comment: which version of eclipse and web logic are you using ?
Have you setup the remote VM to accept connections?  Can you tell a bit more on how you are integrating eclipse with web logic ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya Thanks for your comment. I'm using Eclipse Kepler and Weblo 12c. I have setup in the launching parameter in the setDomainEnv.cmd "-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8022,server=y,suspend=n" to accept connections. In Eclipse I created a new server using the right domain, and tried to launch debug clicking the debug button in the server view.

Comment: Are you running Weblogic with Jrockit? I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Unfortunately no...

Comment: If you change `suspend=n` to `suspend=y` does the JVM stop and wait for a connection?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry for my late response. When I try to change it to 'suspend=y' it waits for a connection and becomes extremely slow at 98% and finally give an error: 'FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]'

Comment: hi, the JVM that your new server is the same that the previous one? have you tried starting your old server on debug mode?

Comment: @Oldskultxo Yes, I haven't changed the JVM. I'm not sure what do you mean by old server, but if you mean before the problem arose, I would say yes: I've started my server on debug mode without error. The awful thing is, after I got the error I've tried many things that I cant remember what exactly I changed caused the error...

Comment: @wceo, can you please get the 'details' section also to understand more on the error in eclipse while starting / having a connection.

Answer (score 1):

In your remote machine, try to disable the firewall and then try connecting it. If firewall is enabled this is a common error we get. 
Ex: service firewalld stop (or) systemctl stop firewalld